# How to use logShow inside the handleAction function in Halogen 5

Tags: functional-programming, purescript, purescript-halogen

As the title says, I am trying to use logShow inside of my handleAction function.
I imported the `Effect.Console (logShow)`
and tried to use it like this, everytime a button is clicked:

```
handleAction ∷ forall o m. Action → H.HalogenM State Action () o m Unit
handleAction = case _ of
  Update -> do
    logShow "Hello"
    H.modify_ \st -> st { field3 = st.field3 + 1 }
```

But I only get the following Error, and I don't understand very much, as I am very new to purescript and functional programming at all.

```
Could not match type

    Effect

  with type

    HalogenM
      { field1 :: Int
      , field2 :: Int
      , field3 :: Int
      }
      Action
      ()
      o0
      m1

while trying to match type Effect t2
  with type HalogenM
              { field1 :: Int
              , field2 :: Int
              , field3 :: Int
              }
              Action
              ()
              o0
              m1
              Unit
while checking that expression (discard (logShow "Hello")) (\$__unused -> modify_ (\st -> ... ))
  has type HalogenM
             { field1 :: Int
             , field2 :: Int
             , field3 :: Int
             }
             Action
             ()
             o0
             m1
             Unit
in value declaration handleAction

where m1 is a rigid type variable
        bound at (line 77, column 16 - line 80, column 51)
      o0 is a rigid type variable
        bound at (line 77, column 16 - line 80, column 51)
      t2 is an unknown type
PureScript(TypesDoNotUnify)
```

I am glad about any clue.

Comment: You can use [traceM](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-debug/4.0.0/docs/Debug.Trace#v:traceM). Or `H.liftEffect $ logShow "hello"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in PS but I'll try my best to answer it. So please correct me if I'm wrong:

`logShow` type signature is `MonadEffect m => Show a => a -> m Unit`, means that the caller of this function should have an instance of or be constrained by `MonadEffect`.

In your case, `handleAction` has a type signature of `forall o m. Action → H.HalogenM State Action () o m Unit` and you call `logShow` inside it. Your `m` here doesn't describe any particular monad while as we knew already, the caller of `logShow` should be constrained by `MonadEffect`.

---

There are a couple of ways to solve this:

1. You can add `MonadEffect` constraint to your `handleAction` type signature like so

   ```
   forall o m. (MonadEffect m) => Action → H.HalogenM State Action () o m Unit
   ```

   This should work since `HalogenM` has instance of `MonadEffect` **as long as** your `m` also has `MonadEffect` instance. See [here](https://github.com/slamdata/purescript-halogen/blob/dd301747260620946956048a86e07e9efe1b6380/src/Halogen/Query/HalogenM.purs#L70)
2. Change your `m` to `Aff` as `Aff` has instance of `MonadEffect`. IIRC, Halogen requires your `m` to be or has an instance of `Aff`
3. Or you could use your own monad stack that has an instance of `Aff` as you can see in [Thomas' great repository here](https://github.com/thomashoneyman/purescript-halogen-realworld/blob/cd1e97aece7d250d4f3c28c5f4e6c0a154a73d11/src/AppM.purs#L123)

---

**EDIT**: The explanation above assumes you import `logShow` from `Effect.Class.Console`

But if you're using `logShow` from `Effect.Console` which has type signature `Show a => a -> Effect Unit`, then we need some function that converts the `Effect` monad to your `m` (this function should have type sig `Effect a -> m a`). And `liftEffect` is exactly what you're looking for.

```
handleAction :: forall o m. (MonadEffect m) => Action → H.HalogenM State Action () o m Unit
handleAction _ = do
  liftEffect $ logShow "something"
  ...
```

Hope this helps :)